# Preciso bloquear o ctrl+v em uma caixa de texto

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5

Quero criar uma input `type="text"` que não permita que colem nada nele. Não precisa apresentar nenhum `alert` nem nada do tipo, apenas não permitir o colar.

Comment: Remover funcionalidades nativas, além de não ser 100% eficiente e seguro, ainda pode confundir e frustrar o usuário. Esse tipo de abordagem deve ser evitado ao máximo.

Comment: isso aqui pode lhe ajudar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394957/how-to-disable-ctrl-c-v-using-javascript-for-both-internet-explorer-and-firefox

Comment: Eu na verdade preciso para uma prova online, que era necessária essa abordagem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Se você estiver usando jQuery na sua aplicação, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

No seu HTML

```
<input type="text" id="texto"></input>
```

No seu Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#texto").bind('paste', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Se você precisar de exemplos de como detectar copia e recorte de texto, nesse post tem exemplos bem legais:

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-detect-copy-paste-and-cut-behavior-with-jquery/

Answer (score 8):

Apenas para acrescentar uma alternativa as opções citadas acima:

```
<input type="text" onpaste="return false" ondrop="return false"/>
```

O atributo `onpaste` pega o evento de colar e o `ondrop` de arrastar. Dessa forma, o usuário será impedido tanto de colar texto (ctrl+v ou botão direito do mouse) quanto de arrastar texto com o mouse para dentro desse campo.

Answer (score 3):

Para evitar Crtl+C Crtl+V ou Crtl+X, pode usar assim também...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#texto').bind('cut copy paste', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
     }); 
 });
```

Comment: o autor da pergunta só precisa saber como evitar `colar`, e o seu método é o mesmo da outra resposta

Answer (score 3):

Se for javascript puro, este modelo *inline* serve:

```
document.getElementById('texto').onpaste = function(){
    return false;
}
```

Se não quiser usar o modo inline, poderá fazer assim (IE > 9):

```
document.getElementById('texto').addEventListener(
    'paste', 
    function(E){
        E.preventDefault();
        return false;
    },
    true
);
```

Neste modo, se precisar incluir IE abaixo da versão 10, precisará condicionar as expressões usando *attachEvent* para IE e *addEventListener* para o restante dos navegadores.

Boa sorte.