# Como Identificar captura de tela

Tags: javascript, html5, captura-de-tela

Como faço para identificar se está acontecendo alguma captura de tela no site.

Por exemplo, a Netflix quando você está assistindo algum filme ou série e tentar tirar um print ela faz com que o resultado do print fique totalmente preto.

Como ela consegue identificar o ato de tirar um print? 
É com javascript?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Preciso bloquear o ctrl+v em uma caixa de texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7524/preciso-bloquear-o-ctrlv-em-uma-caixa-de-texto)

Answer (score 3):

Resposta curta:

***Não existe maneira confiável de detectar captura de tela.***

Resposta longa:

Existem várias maneiras do ambiente operacional capturar o que está sendo exibido; isto é verdade tanto para Windows quando Linux e MacOS. Nem todas as maneiras geram interrupções, e a grande maioria destas não são monitoradas por *browsers*.

O que você vê quando realiza uma captura de tela enquanto assiste Netflix é o resultado de uma outra tecnologia: DRM (*digital rights management*, ou gerência de direitos digitais). Uma função de captura de tela inclui apenas conteúdo que não seja marcado como seguro.

Uma integração entre o serviço de *streaming* (que adiciona DRM ao conteúdo), o *browser* que exibe o stream (que marca as áreas da tela que estão exibindo conteúdo com DRM) e o ambiente operacional (que identifica *displays* seguros que possuem tecnologia de encriptação entre a fonte de vídeo e o dispositivo) permite que você veja o conteúdo, mas previne cópias pelo OS por processos que não sejam parte da cadeia de gerência de direitos.

Comment: Só uma observação: tem muitas situações em que o print de vídeos não é capturado por uma questão técnica simples: as placas de video não desenham o "filme" ou video na tela, e sim num "overlay" (tipo um picture in picture), e isso depende de como o OS está fazendo a montagem desse overlay (era mais comum no XP, sem aceleração 3D). No windows com Aero, por exemplo, as camadas são montadas numa imagem final, então tem mais chance do vídeo aparecer. (a maior parte das vezes que eu vejo tela preta em print de vídeo definitivamente não é por DRM) - Vou deletar o comment depois de vc avisar q leu.

Comment: Eia @Bacco! Sim, você está certo. Eu lembro dessa característica, e que de vez em quando o 'frame' ficava fora da área - o que resultava em uma borda mostrando o fundo do overlay. O exemplo que dei focou no HDCP por causa da abrangência. Obrigado pelo comment - não o apague por favor, pois adiciona ao conteúdo da resposta.